# Ant Design: prevent closing modal conditionally when onOk is called

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I'm using Ant Design v4.22.4 and use `Model` through `useModal`.

I want to keep the modal open conditionally when `onOk` function is called (when ok button is clicked`. Is there way to prevent closing the modal?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this, onOK function expects a function that changes the visibility state, here is a sample code:

```
import { Button, Modal } from 'antd';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const showModal = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(true);
  };

  const handleOk = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(true);
  };

  const handleCancel = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button type="primary" onClick={showModal}>
        Open Modal
      </Button>
      <Modal title="Basic Modal" visible={isModalVisible} onOk={handleOk} onCancel={handleCancel}>
        <p>Some contents...</p>
        <p>Some contents...</p>
        <p>Some contents...</p>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

With this, whenever the user clicks on the OK button, the modal still remains visible.

Comment: Im using `useModal`. Is it still possible with it?